# How to select on going animation with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I know that we can use `:animated` selector to detect animations but it only works for elements animated using jQuery. How can I detect an ongoing keyframe animation with jQuery?

This is my style and markup:

```
div {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 0.9;
  }
}
<div></div>
<div id="mover"></div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
function animateIt() {
  $("#mover").slideToggle("slow", animateIt);
}
animateIt();
$("div:animated").css("background-color","green");
```

It only changes color of `div` with `id` `mover`.

Comment: You can add a css class when you fire the animation and remove it when it is going to end, this way you just check if the class is present or not to check if this is animating or not

Comment: @RohitBandooni Fire which animation? I am not triggering the keyframe animations with jQuery.